# dispatch not doing anything

Tags: reactjs, redux

The action dispatch is not working, The function works and I get the console.log but the store isn't changing. Any ideas?

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import RemoveTodo from './RemoveTodo';
import { remove } from '../actions/Todo';
import { store } from '../app';


class TodosSummary extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
}

onDelete = ({id}) => {
    store.dispatch(remove({id}))
    console.log(store.getState());
};
render () {
    return (
<ul>
{this.props.target.map(({todo, significance, id}) => {
    return (
        <li
         key={id}>{todo} - impact is {significance}
         <button onClick={this.onDelete}>Remove</button>
         </li>
      );
    })}
</ul>


</div>
    );
}

};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
return {
    target: state.target
}; };

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(TodosSummary)
```

This is the action, taking the todo id

```
export const remove = ({id}) => ({
type: 'REMOVE_TODO',
id
});
```

And that's the reducer, filtering the state and bringing back the filtered array

```
const todosReducer  = (state = todosReducerDefaultState, action) => {
switch(action.type) {
    case 'ADD_TODO':
    return [
        ...state,
        action.target
    ];
    case 'REMOVE_TODO':
    return (
        state.filter(({ id }) => id !== action.id)
    );
```

Comment: Why aren't you dispatching from via a method returned from `mapDispatchToProps`?  It looks you like your importing `store` from somewhere and accessing that in your component.  You should *not* do that.  Please refer to this link for a simple example: https://learn.co/lessons/map-dispatch-to-props-readme

Answer (score 1):

I see you want to access `target` property inside `state`. So, the reducer should be like this:

```
case 'ADD_TODO':
    return {
        ...state,
        target: [...state.target, action.target]
    };
case 'REMOVE_TODO':
    return {
        ...state,
        target: state.target.filter(({ id }) => id !== action.id)
    };
```

See if this works.

Comment: Getting a syntax error pointing to the ... dots of state (the first one). Not really sure why

Answer (score 0):

Return updated state like this.

```
 case 'REMOVE_TODO':
    return [...state.filter(({ id }) => id !== action.id)];
```

Comment: Same exact result. Get the console .. state doesn't change

Answer (score 0):

It's not suggested to change the state directly, please change the `addToDo` to the following.

```
Object.assign({}, state, {
    todoList: state.target
});
```

Can you please provide the code snippet for the default state as per your code 'todosReducerDefaultState'?

Comment: const todosReducerDefaultState = [ ] ;